# How to display the correct date century in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have following data in one of my columns:

```
df['DOB']

0    01-01-84
1    31-07-85
2    24-08-85
3    30-12-93
4    09-12-77
5    08-09-90
6    01-06-88
7    04-10-89
8    15-11-91
9    01-06-68
Name: DOB, dtype: object
```

I want to convert this to a datatype column.
I tried following:

```
print(pd.to_datetime(df1['Date.of.Birth']))
0   1984-01-01
1   1985-07-31
2   1985-08-24
3   1993-12-30
4   1977-09-12
5   1990-08-09
6   1988-01-06
7   1989-04-10
8   1991-11-15
9   2068-01-06
Name: DOB, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

How can I get the date as 1968-01-06 instead of 2068-01-06?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this *specific* case, I would use this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'].str[:-2] + '19' + df['DOB'].str[-2:])
```

**Note that this will break if you have DOBs after 1999!**

Output:

```
0   1984-01-01
1   1985-07-31
2   1985-08-24
3   1993-12-30
4   1977-09-12
5   1990-08-09
6   1988-01-06
7   1989-04-10
8   1991-11-15
9   1968-01-06
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Getting error series not defined. Hope that was a typo and have to use column name.

Comment: @Madan Yup, I wanted to change my answer to fit the question and forgot to modify the second reference. Fixed.

Comment: @jezrael Yup, will edit question to specify that clearly

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I will not get dates with year > 1999 in my file.

Answer (score 7):

You can first convert to datetimes and if years are above or equal `2020` then subtract `100` years created by [`DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'], format='%d-%m-%y')
df.loc[df['DOB'].dt.year >= 2020, 'DOB'] -= pd.DateOffset(years=100)
#same like
#mask = df['DOB'].dt.year >= 2020
#df.loc[mask, 'DOB'] = df.loc[mask, 'DOB'] - pd.DateOffset(years=100)
print (df)
         DOB
0 1984-01-01
1 1985-07-31
2 1985-08-24
3 1993-12-30
4 1977-12-09
5 1990-09-08
6 1988-06-01
7 1989-10-04
8 1991-11-15
9 1968-06-01
```

---

Or you can add `19` or `20` to years by [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and set valuies by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with condition.

*Notice: Solution working also for years `00` for `2000`, up to `2020`.*

```
s1 = df['DOB'].str.replace(r'-(\d+)$', r'-19\1')
s2 = df['DOB'].str.replace(r'-(\d+)$', r'-20\1')
mask = df['DOB'].str[-2:].astype(int) <= 20
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(np.where(mask, s2, s1))

print (df)
         DOB
0 1984-01-01
1 1985-07-31
2 1985-08-24
3 1993-12-30
4 1977-09-12
5 1990-08-09
6 1988-01-06
7 1989-04-10
8 1991-11-15
9 1968-01-06
```

---

If all years are below `2000`:

```
s1 = df['DOB'].str.replace(r'-(\d+)$', r'-19\1')
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(s1, format='%d-%m-%Y')
print (df)
         DOB
0 1984-01-01
1 1985-07-31
2 1985-08-24
3 1993-12-30
4 1977-12-09
5 1990-09-08
6 1988-06-01
7 1989-10-04
8 1991-11-15
9 1968-06-01
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line:
df.loc[df['DOB'].dt.year >= 2020, 'DOB'] -= pd.DateOffset(years=100)

Comment: @Madan - first convert values to datetimes and then if some years is higher as `2020` subtract 100 years with [`dateoffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to treat the DOB as a date, and take it back to the previous century only if it is in the future (i.e. after "now"). Example:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'DOB':['01-06-68','01-06-08']})
df['DOB'] = df['DOB'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%d-%m-%y'))
df['DOB'] = df['DOB'].apply(lambda x: x if x<datetime.now() else date(x.year-100,x.month,x.day))
```

Answer (score 0):

In general (in case of uncertainty), it would be better to explicitly specify the year:

```
pd.to_datetime(data['Date.of.Birth'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.split('-')[:-1] + ['19' + x.split('-')[2]])))
```

I ran this with the following data frame:

```
    0   1
0   0   01-01-84
1   1   31-07-85
2   2   24-08-85
3   3   30-12-93
4   4   09-12-77
5   5   08-09-90
6   6   01-06-88
7   7   04-10-89
8   8   15-11-91
9   9   01-06-68


pd.to_datetime(data[1].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.split('-')[:-1] + ['19' + x.split('-')[2]])))


0   1984-01-01
1   1985-07-31
2   1985-08-24
3   1993-12-30
4   1977-09-12
5   1990-08-09
6   1988-01-06
7   1989-04-10
8   1991-11-15
9   1968-01-06
Name: 1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below if there are only `19` and `20` as starts, like:

```
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'].str.replace('20([^20]*)$', '19'))
```

And if there are no `20`s anywhere else:

```
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'].str.replace('20', '19'))
```

And now:

```
print(df['DOB'])
```

Is:

```
0   1984-01-01
1   1985-07-31
2   1985-08-24
3   1993-12-30
4   1977-09-12
5   1990-08-09
6   1988-01-06
7   1989-04-10
8   1991-11-15
9   1968-01-06
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```